# SerpentAI Installation error

Tags: macos, artificial-intelligence

I have been trying to install SerpentAI. I am on a Mac, and I have followed all the steps. I have all the dependencies, but when I use the keyword serpent it gives me this error.

I know I am missing a config file but I don't know where to find it, or how to solve this.

Any command that started with serpent gave me this error.

Here is the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/anaconda3/bin/serpent", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('SerpentAI==2018.1.2', 'console_scripts',         'serpent')()
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
        return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in load_entry_point
        return ep.load()
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2322, in load
        return self.resolve()
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2328, in resolve
        module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SerpentAI-2018.1.2-py3.6.egg/serpent/serpent.py", line 11, in <module>
        from serpent.utilities import clear_terminal, display_serpent_logo, is_linux, is_macos, is_windows, is_unix, wait_for_crossbar
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SerpentAI-2018.1.2-py3.6.egg/serpent/utilities.py", line 8, in <module>
        from serpent.config import config
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SerpentAI-2018.1.2-py3.6.egg/serpent/config.py", line 18, in <module>
        raise Exception("Configuration file not found at: 'config/config.yml'...")
    Exception: Configuration file not found at: 'config/config.yml'...
```

So I think I found the problem, you can clone the GitHub repo, and it will have the config files. Then when you run pip install it will clone a version, and that version won't have the config files.

Comment: which command made u to run into this error?

Comment: I tried any command that started with serpent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to run `serpent vi sual_debugger` after following all installation guide steps.

Try to run `serpent setup`, it might solve the problem you have. It helped in my case.